# How do I access ZPanel (control panel) files?

Tags: control-panel

I've bought a VPS and installed Ubuntu 12.04 on it. To control my domains, I've installed a ZPanel X (10.1.0) control panel, and while this worked perfectly after 4 tries, I cannot access the ZPanel files themselves.

I can create an FTP account within ZPanel, but I can only access the */public_html/* folder, even though I set root/master access to my FTP account. I can't access the folder */panel/*, where the ZPanel files are stored.

You might be asking why I want to do this? I need to configure and edit some ZPanel files.

Comment: You might ask this question on their [forums](http://forums.zpanelcp.com/). If you receive an answer there first, please add it below so the question can be considered closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zpanel FTP users are virtual users that have no right to access the server out of their virtual-root domain directory, so they are not enabled to create such access.

But if you are adminisrator you can login to phpmyadmin as root and change manually the root path of any FTP user: - in database zpanel_core, table x_ftpaccounts, column ft_directory_vc (path relative from zpanel dir, for display and remember) AND - in database zpanel_proftpd, table ftpuser, column homedir (absolute path for ftp access)

But REMEBER that opening an access to /etc/zpanel/panel will give access to all files of the panel, including files that contains login and password for mysql. I ADVISE TO NOT DO IT, or if you require it imperatively to leave it only for a short time and with a real strong password (at last 12 chars mixed from alphanum and case)